# PHP popen process limit?

Tags: php, cron, limit, popen

I'm trying to extract a time consuming task to a separate process. Unfortunately, multi-threading does not really seem to be an option with PHP, but you can create new php processes, using popen.

The use case is this: there is a cronjob that runs every minute, which checks if there are any email campaigns that need to be sent. There could be multiple campaigns that need to be sent at the exact same time, but as of now it just picks up one campaign every minute. I would like to extract sending of the campaigns to a separate process, so that I can send multiple campaigns at the same time.

The code looks something like this (note that this is just a proof of concept):

**crontab**

```
* * * * * root /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/maintask.php 2>&1
```

**maintask.php**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $processName = "Process_{$i}";
    echo "Spawn process {$processName}" . PHP_EOL;

    $process = popen("php subtask.php?process_name={$processName} 2>&1", "r");
    stream_set_blocking($process, false);
}
```

**subtask.php**

```
$process = $_GET['process_name'];

echo "Started sleeping process {$process}" . PHP_EOL;
sleep(rand(10, 40));
echo "Stopped sleeping process  {$process}" . PHP_EOL;
```

Now, the problem I'm having is that popen will only spawn 2 processes at any time, while I'm trying to spawn 4. I can not figure out why. There doesn't appear to be any limit documented. Perhaps this is limited by the amount of cores I have available?

Comment: I've used [proc_open()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) successfully in the past to create multiple child processes. I'll see if I can dig out a code segment

Comment: did you resolve your problem? How do you know your code is only running 2 processes at the same time? the code in your post isn't enough to test this.

Comment: @WeeZel Unfortunately I have not been able to solve this yet. I checked there's just 2 running processes by monitoring the active processes, with "ps -aux". I can see, as soon as one of the subtask.php processes is done, a new one fires up.


I suppose you're right about the provided code. It was an attempt to simply demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve, without posting all the actual code that would make things a bit too complex. I'll see if I can make a working demonstration of my problem and update the original post.


Thanks!

Comment: I know this is not the answer to your question, but would you like to try the class I wrote using `proc_open()` for running parallel processes? (I used it to get `whois` data where each task could take varying amounts of time to return)

Comment: I can definitely give that a shot! Unfortunately the php documentation doesn't clearly state the differences between popen and proc_open, other than the fact that proc_open provides a greater degree of control.

Might be worth a shot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified `subtask.php` so you can see when each task starts, ends and how long it is intending to wait. now you can see when a process starts/stops you can reduce the sleep times - don't need to use `ps -aux` to show when processes are running

**subtask.php**

```
<?php
$process = $argv[1];

$sleepTime = rand(1, 10);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . " - Started sleeping process {$process} ({$sleepTime})" . PHP_EOL;
sleep($sleepTime);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . " - Stopped sleeping process {$process}" . PHP_EOL;
```

I've added the Class into the maintask.php code so you can test it... the fun starts when you `queue()` more entries than you have set `maxProcesses` (try 32)
**NOTE:** the results will come back in the order they complete

**maintask.php**

```
<?php
class ParallelProcess
{
    private $maxProcesses = 16; // maximum processes
    private $arrProcessQueue = [];
    private $arrCommandQueue = [];

    private function __construct()
    {
    }

    private function __clone()
    {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return \static
     */
    public static function create()
    {
        $result = new static();
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param int $maxProcesses
     * @return \static
     */
    public static function load($maxProcesses = 16)
    {
        $result = self::create();
        $result->setMaxProcesses($maxProcesses);
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * get maximum processes
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getMaxProcesses()
    {
        return $this->maxProcesses;
    }

    /**
     * set maximum processes
     *
     * @param int $maxProcesses
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setMaxProcesses($maxProcesses)
    {
        $this->maxProcesses = $maxProcesses;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * number of entries in the process queue
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function processQueueLength()
    {
        $result = count($this->arrProcessQueue);
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * number of entries in the command queue
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function commandQueueLength()
    {
        $result = count($this->arrCommandQueue);
        return $result;
    }


    /**
     * process open
     *
     * @staticvar array $arrDescriptorspec
     * @param string $strCommand
     * @return $this
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    private function p_open($strCommand)
    {
        static $arrDescriptorSpec = array(
            0 => array('file', '/dev/null', 'r'), // stdin is a file that the child will reda from
            1 => array('pipe', 'w'), // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
            2 => array('file', '/dev/null', 'w') // stderr is a pipe that the child will write to
        );

        $arrPipes = array();
        if (($resProcess = proc_open($strCommand, $arrDescriptorSpec, $arrPipes)) === false) {
            throw new \Exception("error: proc_open() failed!");
        }

        $resStream = &$arrPipes[1];

        if (($blnSetBlockingResult = stream_set_blocking($resStream, true)) === false) {
            throw new \Exception("error: stream_set_blocking() failed!");
        }

        $this->arrProcessQueue[] = array(&$strCommand, &$resProcess, &$resStream);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * execute any queued commands
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    private function executeCommand()
    {
        while ($this->processQueueLength() < $this->maxProcesses and $this->commandQueueLength() > 0) {
            $strCommand = array_shift($this->arrCommandQueue);
            $this->p_open($strCommand);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * process close
     *
     * @param array $arrQueueEntry
     * @return $this
     */
    private function p_close(array $arrQueueEntry)
    {
        $resProcess = $arrQueueEntry[1];
        $resStream = $arrQueueEntry[2];

        fclose($resStream);

        $this->returnValue = proc_close($resProcess);

        $this->executeCommand();
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * queue command
     *
     * @param string $strCommand
     * @return $this
     */
    public function queue($strCommand) {
        // put the command on the $arrCommandQueue
        $this->arrCommandQueue[] = $strCommand;
        $this->executeCommand();
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * read from stream
     *
     * @param resource $resStream
     * @return string
     */
    private static function readStream($resStream)
    {
        $result = '';
        while (($line = fgets($resStream)) !== false) {
            $result .= $line;
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * read a result from the process queue
     *
     * @return string|false
     */
    private function readProcessQueue()
    {
        $result = false;
        reset($this->arrProcessQueue);
        while ($result === false && list($key, $arrQueueEntry) = each($this->arrProcessQueue)) {
            $arrStatus = proc_get_status($arrQueueEntry[1]);
            if ($arrStatus['running'] === false) {
                array_splice($this->arrProcessQueue, $key, 1);
                $resStream = $arrQueueEntry[2];
                $result = self::readStream($resStream);
                $this->p_close($arrQueueEntry);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * get result from process queue
     *
     * @return string|false
     */
    public function readNext()
    {
        $result = false;
        if ($this->processQueueLength() === 0) {
        } else {
            while ($result === false and $this->processQueueLength() > 0) {
                $result = $this->readProcessQueue();
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

set_time_limit(0); // don't timeout

$objParallelProcess = ParallelProcess::load(8); // allow up to 8 parallel processes

for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $processName = "Process_{$i}";
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . " - Queue process {$processName}" . PHP_EOL;
    $objParallelProcess->queue("php subtask.php {$processName}"); // queue process
}

// loop through process queue
while (($strResponse = $objParallelProcess->readNext()) !== false) { // read next result and run next command if one is queued
    // process response
    echo $strResponse;
}
```