# Multi tasking with php

Tags: php, multitasking

I made a simple IRC bot that join a channel and do simple tasks based on commands, the bot is working perfectly for 1 server

But now I want it to work on multiple servers on the same time, one solution that I thought of is starting the script multiple times

for example

```
php bot.php server1
php bot.php server2
...etc
```

but I don't like this for a lot of reasons

What are the other ways that I can do multitasking with PHP

Comment: This depends on your codes, which can be modified to allow multi tasking

Comment: I posted a simple multi-process Class recently on SO, why don't you take a look at that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070564/php-popen-process-limit

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty complex topic. I suggest you take a look at libraries like [Amp](https://amphp.org/) and [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) (more oriented towards websockets, but probably can be still used for your case) which are built to simplify tasks like the one you are working on. Making your own solution might prove difficult.